# CSS Angular2- How to apply css to nested element inside one component?

Tags: css, angular

I have one angular component with the html as following:

```
<!-- dynamic content generated runtime -->
<div class="test">
      <div class="testinside">
        HELLO
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now I want to style for one class in the part of [dynamic content generated], so my scss as following:

```
:host {

  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;

  > .test > .testinside {
    color: red;
  }

  > select {
    display: inline;
  }

  > .combobox-container > .input-group {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

[.combobox-container > .input-group] is the css setting for the dynamic content.

However, it seems that the css for dynamic content is not effected :( (the css for static content is OK)

The dynamic content is as following:

```
<common-combobox _ngcontent-hdj-67="" ...>
<!-- dynamic content generated runtime -->
  <div class="combobox-container combobox-selected"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="2"> 
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Anrede" class="combobox"> 
        <span class="input-group-addon dropdown-toggle" data-dropdown="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </span> 
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div _ngcontent-hdj-35="" class="test">
    <div _ngcontent-hdj-35="" class="testinside">
      HELLO
    </div>
  </div>
</common-combobox>
```

Can anyone help me to show the points I missed?

Comment: How do you add dynamic content?  I mean using what?

Comment: I'm using one UI lib from https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `:host /deep/` to force child component use style

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#-deep-

Here is [Live example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/component-styles/ts/eplnkr.html) from Angular, see `hero-detail.component.css`

---

Update from @Joseph Briggs

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

In short, `::ng-deep` will replace `:host /deep/`until next notification from Angular.

Comment: An update:

`The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.`

Comment: As far as I understand that deprecation message,  `::ng-deep` will be removed as well, and there will be no replacement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's gonna be a replacement. Otherwise what do you do if you have a page component that want to show a 3rd party calendar component with a little different styling than the style you want to you use on all other calendars on other pages? related: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17867

Answer (score -1):

Set the [**viewEncapsulation**](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html) for that component to `None`.

Comment: Thanks @Suren, but ViewEncapsulation.None violates our coding rule in project :(

Comment: Although it solves the mentioned problem, it has side effects that you probably don't want.